# Where can I find the documentation for IdocScript for Stellent/Oracle UCM?

Tags: idoc, oracle-ucm, stellent, idocscript

Where can I find the documentation for IdocScript for Stellent/Oracle UCM?  I just got assigned to do maintenance on a page that uses it, and have no prior experience with either Stellent or the script.  My specific problem has to do with string manipulation, but I can hardly find any documentation online at all, odd for a programming-related topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course I answered my own question 15 minutes after I asked it.  Oracle has a guide buried deep in its documentation website. It's available [as a PDF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e10726.pdf) or [in HTML format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e10726/toc.htm) (thanks, [Raystorm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659354/raystorm)).

Comment: There is an [HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e10726/toc.htm) version As well.

For some reason I can't edit the answer to add the link.

Answer (score 6):

If you are after a book, there is the one by Brian Huff (Bex - http://bexhuff.com/) linked below. 
Actually it is the only one. Written before Oracle bought Stellent and may be a missing some IDOC changes.

As a resourse tho it is very handy to have around as it touches on all things UCM (including a decent chunk on IDOC).

[*The Definitive Guide to Stellent Content Server Development*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596846)
~ Brian Huff

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out that book was on my boss's shelf.  A little broader than I needed since I won't be working with the UCM much in general, but helpful.