# IDoc Beginners tutorial

Tags: idoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a tutorial for IdocScript for Stellent/Oracle UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766079/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-for-idocscript-for-stellent-oracle-ucm)

Hi All,

Can someone point me to a good BEGINNERS tutorials on IDoc. I basically need to understand the IDoc format.

I tried googling , but not able to find a beginners introductory tutorial to IDoc.

pardon me for being a noob at googling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added an answer to a similar question here;

[Where can I find the documentation for IdocScript for Stellent/Oracle UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766079/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-for-idoc-script-for-stellent-oracle-ucm)

Don't sweat on the google part. There really isn't much around as IDOC is only used in Oracle UCM (formerly Stellent)

Afaik, there is nothing specifically targeted to Beginners. Best bet out of the book/pdf is to start creating copies of fragments (inside Site Studio Designer) and working out what makes them tick.